# Is it possible to create a Hotkey for Context Menu items that use Context Menu Handlers?

Tags: windows, contextmenu, autohotkey, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I have a [shell extension](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm) that allows me to save/restore desktop icon locations. Its commands run completely from the Desktop Context Menu. I would like to add a hotkey to these items within the context menu.

I'm not a programmer by any means, but I can follow instructions. I poked around a bunch and it looks like there are registry keys and ways to edit the Accelerator Keys, but that still requires opening the context menu.

I have [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) set up to use my hotkey to open the context menu and select the option if I'm on the desktop and that's been a fine workaround, but I'd still like to know for the future if it's possible to do without a script .

```
$^r::
    If (IsDeskTopActive()) {
        WinActivate, Program Manager ahk_class Progman
    Send, {AppsKey}{d}

}

    Else 
        SendInput {^r}
Return

IsDesktopActive() { ; Modified by errorseven - orignal by HotKeyIt
    MouseGetPos,,,win
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %win%
    If class in Progman,WorkerW
        Return True
    Return False
}
```

Code is working as intended. Just looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Locate `DesktopCmd.exe` in `Desktop Restore` install directory (**C:\Program Files\Desktop Restore**).

Open `cmd` in that directory and run `DesktopCmd.exe /?` help file to see all available commands.

You can then assign the command to the hotkey:

**SAVE**

```
$^s::
    If (IsDeskTopActive()) {
        WinActivate, Program Manager ahk_class Progman
        Run, C:\Program Files\Desktop Restore\DesktopCmd.exe save /n "MyLayout" /y, , Hide
    }
    Else 
        SendInput {^r}
```

**RESTORE**

```
$^r::
    If (IsDeskTopActive()) {
        WinActivate, Program Manager ahk_class Progman
        Run, C:\Program Files\Desktop Restore\DesktopCmd.exe restore /n "MyLayout" /y, , Hide
    }
    Else 
        SendInput {^r}
```